A required class was missing while executing org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema: org/apache/avro/Schema$Parser
We recently added Kafka automation in our project and with the new consumer account created, we were able to poll to the topic and consume the messages in our local. When I tried to push the code into gitlab pipeline , my build is failing with the below error.
"[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema (default) on project: Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.11.3:schema: org/apache/avro/Schema$Parser"

I tried all the ways and finally posting here. Do we need to add any code in gitlab-ci-yml file?
POM.XML has below dependencies added: I am using generate resources by taking avroschema file (avsc files) from source folder and generate the Java classes.
`<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-avro-serializer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/avro</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>`

Gitlab.Yml file :
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: >-
    -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository

default:
  image: $CONTAINER_PATH/maven-container

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

build-project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn test-compile
    - mvn generate-sources -U -X

build-nightly:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - special-tag
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
  script:
    - mvn test -Dgroups=$SMOKE_GROUP
  allow_failure: false
  rules:
    - if: $SMOKE_GROUP

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn site`
    - mv target/site public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"


What do you have avro.version set as? The maven plugin may need a different one to find the class in the error

<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
<avro.version>1.11.3</avro.version>
<confluent.version>7.6.1</confluent.version>
This is avro version and maven compiler version

Well, Schema$Parser should exist, so you can try searching your ~/m2/repository for that class to see if it is in the classpath
